# Почему нельзя создать константу типа T в обобщении по T (ошибка CS1959)?

Tags: c#, .net, const

Почему нельзя создать константу `B` в примере ниже, ведь её тип ссылочный?

```c#
   class SomeClass { }

   static class Consts<T> where T : class
   {
      public const SomeClass A = null;

      // Error CS1959  
      // 'Consts<T>.B' is of type 'T'. 
      // The type specified in a constant declaration must be sbyte, byte, short, ushort, 
      // int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, 
      // string, an enum-type, or a reference-type.
      public const T B = null;

      // Менее эффективно чем константа.
      public static readonly T C = null;

      static void Foo()
      {
         SomeClass s1 = Consts<SomeClass>.A;
         SomeClass s2 = Consts<SomeClass>.B;
         SomeClass s3 = Consts<SomeClass>.C;
      }
   }
```

Использовались:

.NET Framework 4.8

C# 7.3

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152005/discussion-on-question-by-------t--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817979/where-t-class-generic-constraint-and-const-value-declaration

Comment: @Андрей, похоже, что это ограничение именно языка C#. Во всяком случае CIL мне позволил спокойно определить _null_-константу обобщённого типа.